# "No detected operating systems" - What should I do?

Tags: system-installation, boot, dual-boot

I am a first time linux user trying to install elementary os on my old macbook. I followed a guide on elementary.io/docs/installation on how to install it.  I got the ISO image on a usb and rebooted my computer.  Once I opened the boot selection screen I selected the "EFI BOOT", which opened up the installation screen.  Unfortunately, the screen says "No other detected operating systems".  It gives me an option to erase the hard drive and install the os (which i do not want to do) and another option which i am not comfortable with.  I have no idea what to do from here and i do not want to erase OSX.  Any help on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: refer [here](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2476/install-elementary-os-in-dual-boot-with-something-else-option)

Answer (score 1):

I thought the same and apparently is because you are trying to install EFI and UEFI, test mode (if your BIOS permits) in LEGACY mode.
Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have the problem when I first deleted the partition where I wanted to install elementary.
It used to be an option in the installer. The installer asked you if you want to install in this empty space. That was nice. Now it doesnt ask you this specific but it still does this I think.
At least somehow it worked with my install.