# Install elementary OS in dual boot with 'something else' option

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot

How to install elementary OS using the *'Something else'* option at the partitioning step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note** : This can also be used to reinstall elementary OS. To reinstall skip the partition steps.

---

**Partitoning** :

Before using *something else* option allocate space to install elementary OS.

Open Gparted then select partiton you want to allocate for elementary OS.
Right click --> **Delete.**

**Step1**: Now right click on the partition --> New --> **extended partition.** and **ext4** File system.

> [image: Imgur]

**Step2** : Make Partitions for `swap`, `/root` and `/home`.

Now Right click on the `/sda2` and select `Resize/Move`

Here -- sda2  extended

```
   sda5 format swap - 
   sda6 format ext4 - 
   sda7 format ext4 -
```

**Note**:

1. You can choose `swap`  size same as size of your RAM. Generally 4GB swap is enough.
2. `20 GiB` is enough for `/root`.

   See [system specifications](https://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#recommended-system-specifications), *at least* 15 GB of disk space needed.
3. `/home` is the filesystem for your user's files: documents, images, music and videos

   > [image: Imgur]

Now your partition table similar to like this:

> [image: Imgur]

---

**Installation**:

Now start installing and then select `something else` option.

> [image: Imgur]

Now,

select `/sda5` --> click on <kbd>change</kbd> button (at left corner) you will see popup like this:

> [image: Imgur]

Now click on drop down button select `swap area`.

> [image: Imgur]

Similarly for `/sda6` and `/sda7` select `ext4 /` and `ext4 /home` respectively.

Now click on <kbd>Install Now</kbd>