# Can I install Freya alongside of Windows 7?

Tags: release-freya, microsoft-windows

I am using windows 7 for my main works. now I am learning Freya gradually to move my entire things to Freya. But now, I am practicing with it. So, I want to install Freya alsongside Windows 7.

1. How can I install Freya? 
   Whether I need any unused partition to use it on Freya. or it will use the Windows 7 partitions.
2. Will it slow down if I install both OS together ?
3. Both should not Conflict with Partitions. In future I will any one OS. Can I do it without crash problems?

I am newbie to Freya. So my question may not meet the forum standards. so please don't vote it down.

Comment: Can you add details like, your  RAM and Hard disk size?

Comment: its Pentium Dual Core And 
2 GB DDR3 RAM And 
500 GB HDD

Comment: here you can see more details my lap http://www.flipkart.com/asus-x551ca-sx043d-x-pentium-dual-core-2-gb-ddr3-500-hdd-free-dos/p/itmdtazgz3vt2ftg

Comment: One note of concern I'd like to add during installation of EOS freya, please do it with internet connected. If not, grub will not be installed and you cannot boot any OS. I think the defect is in official ISO file. Thats the problem I faced (dual booting with win10. However, no data lost). Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I install Freya? Whether I need any unused partition to use it on Freya. or it will use the Windows 7 partitions.

**Backup Data**

**Step 1: Getting Prepared**:

- Install windows first. (Since you already have Windows installed, that’s fine.)
- **Make Room for  elementary** :

  Create a seperate partition for elementary. This will save you some time later.

  [image: Imgur]

**Step 2**: Install elementary:

- [Create a bootable usb](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).
- After completely shutdown your system. Now connect your live usb, start your computer and change BIOS boot order. (Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> while booting, the key may be different for you)
- Now select "Try elementary"
- Now start installing elementary, Go through the installer until you reach an option that asks where (or how) you want to install the elementary. (This is the main step, be careful, simple mistake will wipe windows)

  *Case 1*: If you have "Install elementary along side windows" option, then proceed with that option.

  *Case 2* : If you **don't** have the above option, select "something else" option.

  See [Install elementary OS in dual boot with 'something else' option](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2476/install-elementary-os-in-dual-boot-with-something-else-option)

> Will it slow down if I install both OS together ?

Probably not. It mainy depends on your RAM and your work. Create `swap` partition.

> Both should not Conflict with Partitions. In future I will any one OS. Can I do it without crash problems?

Create other partitions in ntfs format so that it can be recogniged by both elementary and freya. Also install elementary in **extended partition**.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it now.  `Case 1: If you have "Install elementary along side windows" option, then proceed with that option.`. This one i am fearing now. If I don't find, than the windows may wiped. Because i have huge datas inside Windows.

Comment: 'huge data"? please backup, thats what I can suggest now :)

Comment: Can't stress enough how important it is to back up your important data BEFORE attempting this. Even if the installation goes off without a hitch, understand that resizing partitions can be potentially disastrous and you really should have the data backed up anyway.

Comment: ALWAYS RESIZE YOUR WINDOWS PARTITION IN WINDOWS, DO NOT USE GPARTED OR ANYTHING ELSE. You could screw up your Windows install otherwise.