# How much space does elementary OS need in dualboot?

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot

I have a 128 GB SSD and Windows 7 is already installed. Now I want to install elementary OS on a second partition. How many space do I need at least for elementary OS?

Hope you can help me.
Regards Niklas!

Comment: Also see [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3139/can-i-install-freya-alongside-of-windows-7/3140#3140) and [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2476/install-elementary-os-in-dual-boot-with-something-else-option/2477#2477)

Comment: The question is not about *how to install*, but about the space needed. I don't see the linked answers really being clear regarding that.

Comment: To clarify, the posts *do* talk about space needed, but not really backed by any info / links. I'm not sure "should be enough" is an adequate statement.

Comment: I have edited both the posts, now its a dup, right?

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Sorry my question was unclear. So I want to creat a root, home and swap partition and I was not sure how big the root partition should be at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [official installation guide](https://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#recommended-system-specifications) **recommends** at least **15 GB free space** and the installer **requires 6.4 GB**. The base operating system itself won't take much more space (in fact it most likely takes less space than 15GB), but if you want to install more applications and save some data (e.g. movies or music) on the partition, you should go with a bit more, depending on your use-case.