# Will installing elementary OS Juno going to wipe data on other drives?

Tags: system-installation

I have a pc with three logical partitions. I have windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 installed on two of them. I am planning on wiping the Ubuntu partition to install elementary OS Juno to try it out, is it going to affect any other partitions or such?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install elementary OS in dual boot with 'something else' option](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2476/install-elementary-os-in-dual-boot-with-something-else-option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to chose the good option and take care during installation: selecting the last option in that list - the one that allows you to access and administer partitions - namely: "Something else".

[image]

There, you can select the partition you want for elementary, and it will be installed there - and only there. Nothing else will be touched, unless you decide otherwise.

Also [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/2476/170) on elementaryos.stackexchange.

[This](https://itsfoss.com/guide-install-elementary-os-luna/) tutorial for Luna is still valid, the installer is the same.